# PHP & MySQL: Select account from database which hasn't been refreshed for more than 2 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I have something like this in my database:

```
ID | ACCOUNT | PASSWORD | LAST_REFRESH  
1  | acc1    | pass1    | 1386506130
```

And in my PHP script I have this:

```
$allowed_time = time() - 121;
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT account FROM accounts WHERE last_refresh >= '.$allowed_time.'');
```

But if I try this query, nothing will be returned, even if $allowed_time is bigger than last_refresh in the database.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `'` at the end.

Comment: Try replacing `.$allowed_time.''` with `.$allowed_time`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT account FROM accounts WHERE last_refresh >= $allowed_time");
```

Using double quotes for your query will allow you to use variables without concatenating them. Also, you're trying to compare a number and originally you were wrapping the variable in sinle quotes causing mysql to read it as a string rather than a number.

Hope this helps! :)